# Receiving multiple datagrams in a single system call

Tags: linux, network-programming

On Linux, unless I'm mistaken, an application can use the socket call family to send or receive one packet at a time on datagram transports.

Would like to know if Linux provides a means for the application to send and receive multiple packets in a single call on datagram transports.

Comment: It's not provided by the BSD API (that's what you called the "socket call family").

Comment: On linux you might want to have a look at the sendmmsg syscall

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use recvmmsg to receive multiple datagram packets (example UDP)

```
int recvmmsg(int sockfd, struct mmsghdr *msgvec, unsigned int vlen,
                    unsigned int flags, struct timespec *timeout);
DESCRIPTION         
   The recvmmsg() system call is an extension of recvmsg(2) that allows
   the caller to receive multiple messages from a socket using a single
   system call. ...
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmmsg.2.html

Use sendmmsg to send...

```
int sendmmsg(int sockfd, struct mmsghdr *msgvec, unsigned int vlen,
                    unsigned int flags);
DESCRIPTION        
   The sendmmsg() system call is an extension of sendmsg(2) that allows
   the caller to transmit multiple messages on a socket using a single
   system call.
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmmsg.2.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no such call on Linux. However, depending what you need, there are alternatives:

- Both sendmsg() and recvmsg() can do "scatter/gather" - send/receive a single packet from multiple buffers.
- "pktgen" ( http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/pktgen ) is a kernel module which can transmit millions of packets with just a handful of file writes for the testing purposes.

Comment: For now, I'm using the io_*() family of async IO calls to solve my purpose. The async IO is a bit of a cheat, but it facilitates sending/receiving multiple packets at a time.